# Fetch content from DOM using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to fetch content between two comment tags:

HTML:

```
<!--googleon:all-->
<div>return this</div>
<!--googleoff:all-->
<div>not important</div>
<!--googleon:all-->
<div>and this</div>
<!--googleoff:all-->
<div>ignore</div>
<!--googleon:all-->
<div>and this</div>
```

JS:

```
$.fn.getComments = function () {
    return this.contents().map(function () {
        if (this.nodeType === 8 && this.nodeValue.match("googleon:all")) return this.nodeValue;
    }).get();
}

var comments = $('body').getComments();
```

However, it's returning all content, and not matching the comment value. I'm expecting:

```
return this
and this
and this
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hErbL/197/)

Comment: Should `comments` hold those 3 lines as an array?

Comment: @JakeParis array works fine

Comment: It's because when you are return `this.nodeValue`, that's the nodeValue for the comment. It seems like you're wanting to get the _next_ node's value.

Comment: It is not returning all of the content, you see the content because it is in your markup. If you console `comments` you can see it is returning the comments that you want. Which is `googleon:all`. However it looks like you are actually looking for the node value between on and off and not the comment itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `map` for this, you have to remember whether you're in an "on" or "off" section yourself. Roughly:

```js
$.fn.getComments = function () {
    // Remember whether we're gathering or not
    var gathering = false;
    // Gather into this array
    var elements = [];
    // Look through contents
    this.contents().each(function () {
        switch (this.nodeType) {
            case 8:
                // Comment, does it change our gathering flag?
                if (this.nodeValue.includes("googleon:all")) {
                    gathering = true;
                } else if (this.nodeValue.includes("googleoff:all")) {
                    gathering = false;
                }
                break;
            case 1: // Element
            // Add case 3: if you want text nodes too
                // Push it if we're gathering
                if (gathering) {
                    elements.push(this.innerHTML);
                }
                break;
        }
    })
    return elements;
};

console.log($(document.body).getComments());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<!--googleon:all-->
<div>return this</div>
<!--googleoff:all-->
<div>not important</div>
<!--googleon:all-->
<div>and this</div>
<!--googleoff:all-->
<div>ignore</div>
<!--googleon:all-->
<div>and this</div>
<!--googleoff:all-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You may well have to tweak that (for instance, maybe you want an array of arrays, where there's one entry for each region between on/off markers and the entries within that are arrays of all nodes in that region), but it should get you going the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you can do

```js
$("body").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 8;
}).each(function(idx, elem) {
  if (elem.nodeValue == 'googleon:all') {
    console.log($(this).next().html())
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--googleon:all-->
<div>return this</div>
<!--googleoff:all-->
<div>not important</div>
<!--googleon:all-->
<div>and this</div>
<!--googleoff:all-->
<div>ignore</div>
<!--googleon:all-->
<div>and this</div>
```

Comment: Assuming there's only one element between them (as in the question), never more than one.